# What it's the key and chord progression of this four part harmony music

Tags: chord-theory, chord-progressions, beginner, voice-leading

I'm trying to write a four-part harmony song with some suspended chords and stuff. I'm having some problems identifying the chords, I'm also not sure if the key is in F. Can anyone help me? I'm also trying to learn some voice leading and I noticed that it has a parallel fifth at the end of the first measure and the beginning of the second one[image]

I also really would appreciate it if anyone could give me more content to study four-part harmony and voice leading. I really like Jazz and dissonances.

Comment: If we answer your question, you’ll have those answers, but not the understanding of the music theory that leads to those answers. Having the answers won’t help you with your writing. Having the understanding will. So now you know there are gaps in your music theory and you’d like to understand these things. So you would be best served by studying more music theory instead of just having us give you a few answers that won’t really help you.

Comment: It's not unusual for a four-part harmonization not to reveal what key it's in until the end.  Without seeing the whole thing, we can't be very certain about the key.